# Delay foreach and while loop for 30 seconds php

Tags: php, delay, sleep

I have some application for Google scrap, for some keywords. In table I have list of keywords. This is the logic I used to scrap, each keyword with different proxy.

```
foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
   $response = false;
   while ($response == false) {
     try {
       ScrapGoogle();
     } catch (Exception $e) {
       $response = false;
       // If false, try another proxy. I didn't included that block code here
     }
   }
}
```

Because of this logic I'm getting sometimes error 503, but while testing manually that proxy (from web browser), Google search works. Which means I need to stop foreach and/or while loop for 30 seconds. I tried to add sleep() in the end of both loops but I didn't get any better. Loop wait 30 seconds and than run all checks in the same time.

Comment: Could the issue be within `ScrapGoogle()` itself? Are you sure the proxy is switching with your script the same way as when you do it manually? You may want to print out the proxy you're connected to each time in the console or a log.

Comment: No, since I have some logs system, I write every request into db, so I know script is working because there is proper proxy switching. I even added unique proxy for every keyword. The only problem I'm facing is that some of this loops don't work correctly, and get results for all keywords at the same time, or it checks very quickly